# Grails 1.3.7 - Very Large Heap Size

Tags: grails, heap-memory

I have a problem while using grails. You see, when running grails 1.3.7, i realize that the heap size is increasing rapidly. Though I tried to clear the heap size using the heap size garbage collection, it does not work. This really cause a big problem to me as grails keeps on "Not Responding". Tried to restart my laptop and even restarted grails numerous times, but none of it works. The current maximum heap size I use is 990M.

Please help and advise.

Thanks

Comment: 1.3.7 is pretty old. Maybe it's time to upgrade?

Comment: Grails 1.x, really!! Anyways, what's your `GRAILS_OPTS`?

Comment: @Todd Sharp: I wanted to but too bad cannot cos my company is running on 1.3.7

Comment: @ShashankAgrawal: I hope this is what you asking for:

-Xms128m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.IEVersion=10001